# On this site we obey the laws of thermodynamics!

Tags: string, code-challenge, sequence

And in particular the [second law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics): *the entropy of an isolated system undergoing an irreversible process increases with time*.

For this challenge,

- An "*isolated system*" will be taken to be a *program or function* (abbreviated as "program" from now on);
- The "*irreversible process*" will be *execution* of code;
- The passing of "*time*" will correspond to *iterated executions of the program's output*, considered as a new program;
- "*Entropy*" will be taken as *Shannon's first-order entropy* (to be defined below), which is a measure of how diverse the characters of the string are.

### The challenge

Your program should produce a non-empty string that when executed as a program in the same language produces a string with more entropy than the previous one. Infinitely iterating this execute-the-output process must produce a **strictly increasing sequence of entropy values**.

The strings can contain any [Unicode 9.0](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/) characters. The sequence of strings must be deterministic (as opposed to random).

The **entropy** for a given string will be defined as follows. Identify its unique characters and their number of occurrences in the string. The frequency *p<sub>i</sub>* of the *i*-th unique character is the number of occurrences of that character divided by the length of the string. The entropy is then

[image]

where the sum is over all unique characters of the string. Technically, this corresponds to the [entropy of a discrete random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) with distribution given by the frequencies observed in the string.

Let *H<sub>k</sub>* denote the entropy of the string produced by the *k*-th program, and let *H*<sub>0</sub> denote the entropy of the initial program's code. Also, let *L*<sub>0</sub> denote the length of the initial program in characters. The sequence {*H<sub>k</sub>*} is monotone as per the challenge requirements, and is bounded (because the number of existing characters is finite). Therefore it has a limit, *H*<sub>∞</sub>.

The **score** of a submission will be (*H*<sub>∞</sub>−*H*<sub>0</sub>)/*L*<sub>0</sub>:

- The numerator, *H*<sub>∞</sub>−*H*<sub>0</sub>, reflects to what extent your code "obeys" the law of increasing entropy over an infinite time span.
- The denonimator, *L*<sub>0</sub>, is the length of the initial code in characters (not in bytes).

The code with the **highest score wins**. Ties will be resolved in favour of the earliest submission/edit.

To compute the entropy of a string, you can use the JavaScript snippet (courtesy of [@flawr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24877/flawr) and with corrections by [@Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) and [@ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions)) at the end of this post.

If obtaining the limit *H*<sub>∞</sub> is difficult in your specific case, you can use any lower bound, say *H*<sub>20</sub>, to compute the score (so you would use (*H*<sub>20</sub>−*H*<sub>0</sub>)/*L*<sub>0</sub>). But in any case, the infinite sequence of entropies must be strictly increasing.

Please include an explanation or short proof that the sequence of entropies is increasing, if that's not evident.

### Example

In a fictional language, consider the code `aabcab`, which when run produces the string `cdefgh`, which when run produces `cdefghi`, which ...

The unique characters of the original code are `a`, `b` and `c`, with respective frequencies 3/6, 2/6 and 1/6. Its entropy is 1.4591. This is *H*<sub>0</sub>.

The string `cdefgh` has more entropy than `aabcab`. We can know this without computing it because for a given number of characters the entropy is maximized when all the frequencies are equal. Indeed, the entropy *H*<sub>1</sub> is 2.5850.

The string `cdefghi` again has more entropy than the previous one. We can know without computing because adding a non-existing character always increases the entropy. Indeed, *H*<sub>2</sub> is 2.8074.

If the next string were `42` the chain would be invalid, because *H*<sub>3</sub> would be 1, smaller than 2.8074.

If, on the other hand, the sequence went on producing strings of increasing entropy with limit *H*<sub>∞</sub> = 3, the score would be (3−1.4597)/6 = 0.2567.

### Acknowledgments

Thanks to

- [@xnor](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) for his help improving the challenge, and in particular for convincing me that infinite chains of increasing entropy obtained from iterated execution are indeed possible;
- [@flawr](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24877/flawr) for several suggestions, including modifying the score function, and for writing the very useful snippet;
- [@Angs](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/60340/angs) for pointing out an essential drawback in a previous definition of the score function;
- [@Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) for a correction in the JavaScript snippet;
- [@ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions) for another correction in the snippet;
- [@PeterTaylor](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/194/peter-taylor) for a correction in the definition of entropy.

### Snippet for calculating the entropy

```js
function calculateEntropy() {
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value; // fetch input as string
  if (/[\uD800-\uDBFF]([^\uDC00-\uDFFF]|$)|([^\uD800-\uDBFF]|^)[\uDC00-\uDFFF]/.test(input)) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = " invalid (unmatched surrogates)";
    return;
  }
  var charArray = input.match(/[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[^]/g);
  var frequency = {};
  for (var ind in charArray) {
    frequency[charArray[ind]] = 0;
  }
  var total = 0;
  for (var ind in charArray) {
    frequency[charArray[ind]] ++;
    total++;
  }
  var entropy = 0;
  for (var key in frequency) {
    var p = frequency[key] / total;
    entropy -= p * Math.log2(p);
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = " " + entropy;
};
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="javascript:calculateEntropy();">calculate</button>Entropy: <span id="output">NaN</span> 
<br/>
<textarea id="input">asdf asdf</textarea>
```

Comment: “On this site we obey the laws of thermodynamics!” [citation-needed]

Comment: Here is the [source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dc-m9dumEaw) :-)

Comment: Is there any constraint on the length of the output? Like having the same amount of characters than the input for instance. I find this unclear.

Comment: I was hoping the question would be about "Hot" Network Questions.

Comment: @Osable The outputs can have any length you want

Comment: I was wondering... is it actually possible to infinitely strictly increase the entropy? If I take the output in its unsigned binary form, it's basically a sequence of integers in range [0,255]. If the entropy is optimal when all the characters are different (just an assumption), wouldn't it imply that the string with largest entropy is 256 bytes long? It's far from being infinite. Or my assumption is wrong.

Comment: @Osable Attach a copy of that string to itself and the entropy will be the same. Then remove one char and it will be slightly smaller. Invert the process and you have increased the entropy. If you manage to never reach the maximum entropy, you can keep on increasing forever

Comment: Hmm it's that last sentence that I did not figure out first. Now that's clear. I thought we had to produce something with an 'infinite' entropy.

Comment: @Osable Yes, quite a few people seem to be confused by that... :( But the challenge says "strictly increasing sequence" (not "strictly increasing sequence that tends to infinity"). And the example has limit entropy of 3

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes because we went a little too fast. Anyway can the input value be balanced (I mean, all characters have the same frequency)?

Comment: @Osable There On this challenge there is no input really. If you mean the initial string (initial program), it can be whatever you want

Comment: @Osable there's a [concrete example](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100243/20283) now, if that helps.

Comment: I assume that that "pseudorandom" is not, for the purposes of this challenge, "deterministic"?

Comment: @Stephen The sequence of strings has to be the same for every chain of executions. Pseudorandom is acceptable if you can achieve that, for example using always the same seed

Comment: I realize the question is about coding rather than thermodynamics, but your statement of the 2nd law should read something like "the entropy of a [macroscopic] isolated system cannot decrease", rather than that it increases with time.  That's b/c the entropy of an isolated system at equilibrium doesn't change. Yes, there's no such thing as a fully isolated system in the real world, but, based on the def. of an isolated system, one can't make the general statement that its entropy will always increase with time.  [And implicit in all of this is that the 2nd law applies to macroscopic systems.]

Comment: @theorist Good point. I included "applied to irreversible processes" in the first paragraph (I need increasing entropy because the challenge is about strings with strictly increasing entropy)

Comment: OK, now you'll just want to clean up the language.  To the left of the colon you're referring to the process, while to the right you're referring to the system.  Since you're in fact you're referring to a combination of both, separating the two with the colon makes things a bit confusing.  I'd recommended instead writing:  "And in particular the second law, which says that the entropy of an isolated system undergoing an irreversible process increases with time."

Comment: @theorist Thanks, edited. I also extended the analogy to incorporate the "irreversible process", which corresponds to "code execution"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Jelly, 0.68220949

```
“ȷ6ȷ5rỌ,®Ṿ€ṁṾY⁾©v⁸⁵”©v⁵
```

**H<sub>90</sub> = 19.779597644909596802, H<sub>0</sub> = 4.088779347361360882, L<sub>0</sub> = 23**

I used long doubles to compute **H<sub>90</sub>**. Double precision floats incorrectly reported that **H<sub>47</sub> < H<sub>46</sub>**

The first program prints

```
“…”
“ȷ6ȷ5rỌ,®Ṿ€ṁṾY⁾©v⁸⁵”©v1010
```

where `…` serves as a placeholder for all Unicode characters with code points between **100,000** and **1,000,000**. The actual length is **900,031** characters.

The seconds program prints

```
“…”
“ȷ6ȷ5rỌ,®Ṿ€ṁṾY⁾©v⁸⁵”
“…”
“ȷ6ȷ5rỌ,®Ṿ€ṁṾY⁾©v⁸⁵”©v101010
```

which, in turn, prints

```
“…”
“ȷ6ȷ5rỌ,®Ṿ€ṁṾY⁾©v⁸⁵”
“…”
“ȷ6ȷ5rỌ,®Ṿ€ṁṾY⁾©v⁸⁵”
“…”
“ȷ6ȷ5rỌ,®Ṿ€ṁṾY⁾©v⁸⁵”©v10101010
```

etc.

None of these programs works in the online interpreter, which has a **100 KB** output limit. However, if we modify the program to print `0123456789` instead of the aforementioned **900,000** Unicode characters, you can [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcNTcgNDhy4buMLMKu4bm-4oKs4bmB4bm-WeKBvsKpduKBuOKBteKAncKpduKBtQ&input=)

Answer (score 6):

## MATLAB, <s>9.6923e-005</s> 0.005950967872272

```
H0 =  2.7243140535197345, Hinf = 4.670280547752703, L0 = 327
```

This new version is an improved version of the first "proof of concept". In this version I get a great score increase from the first iteration. This was achieved by "blowing up" the output of the first program, that is replicated by all the subsequent ones. Then I also tried to find the minimal `H0` by just appending the most common symbol of the code as many times as possible. (This had obviously a limit, since it does not only decrease `H0` but also increases `L0` at the same time. You can see the development of the score plotted against the size of the program where the size is varied by just adding or removing `1`.) The subsequent iterations still are equivalent to the previous version below.

```
a=['ns}z2e1e1116k5;6111gE16:61kGe1116k6111gE16:6ek7;:61gg3E1g6:6ek7;:61gg3E1'];11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111;;disp(['[''',a+1,'''];',0,'a=[''',a,'''];',0,[a-10,']]);'],0,[a-10,']]);']]);
```

[image: Score vs Program length]

#### Previous version:

```
H0 = 4.22764479010266, Hinf = 4.243346286312808, L0 = 162
```

The following code is inspired by the [matlab quine](http://blog.garritys.org/2009/10/quines.html). It basically outputs just itself again *twice*. The clue is that for any iteration we have `n` lines of code and `n-1` newline symbols `\n`. So as `n` approaches to infinity, the ratio of lines of code to newlines approaches 1, and at the same time this guarantees that we have a strictly monotonous growth in entropy. That also means we can easily calculate `Hinf` by just considering the zero-th generation code with equally many newlines as lines of code. (Which one can experimentally confirm, as it converges quite quickly.)

```
a=['ns}z2e1kGe1116k6111gE16;:61kGe1116k6111gE16;:6ek7;:61gg3E1g6;:6ek7;:61gg3E1'];
disp(['a=[''',a,'''];',10,'a=[''',a,'''];',10,[a-10,']]);'],10,[a-10,']]);']]);
```

Comment: Very nice! Would you gain something replacing `10` by `0` (and adjusting the rest of the code for that)? Char `0` is displayed as space by Matlab

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Let me try it, but I think there are some other improvements that would increase the score a lot more. This should first of all be a proof of concept :)

Comment: I included now your suggestion along with a bunch of other improvements.

Comment: I like that optimization graph :-)